# unfortunately <app name> has stopped. (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to run my app with my phone(Galaxy Nexus) but it constantly shows an error: `Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped.`

Here's my `styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <itemname="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#872657</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#872657</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#dfe3ee</item>
        <item name="android:background">#872657</item>

    </style>



    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#dfe3ee</item></style>

</resources>
```

Here's my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#872657">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialer_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:background="#dfe3ee"
        android:onClick="onGetNameClick"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter Your Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialer_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dialer_button"
        android:textColor="#fefbf7"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter Your Phone Number"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#fefbf7"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter E-Mail ID"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#fefbf7"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter Emergency Contact Number"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
        android:textColor="#fefbf7"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="App Coded by ©Ananay Batra"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:textColor="#fefbf7"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView></RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my `MainActivity.java`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }
```

Here's my `Second_layout1.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#872657">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Follow Me"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:textColor="#fefbf7"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Post Location on Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="#dfe3ee"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Message to Emergency Contact"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#dfe3ee"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

I would really like someone to reply!!
And also please explain what I did wrong in my code

logcat:

```
4758-4758/com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-24 01:39:13.014    4758-4758/com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ffba8)
04-24 01:39:13.030    4758-4758/com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia, PID: 4758
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia/com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:152)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at com.example.ananaybatra.rape_freeindia.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat (any errors you are getting)

Comment: Please post your LogCat (any errors you are getting)

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Answer (score 0):

In the `Second_layout1.xml` you position the first `RadioButton` (id `radioButton`) relative to the position of the `LinearLayout` (id `linearLayout`) which is defined after the `RadioButton`.

You need to change it to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="left"
android:padding="20dp"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="#872657">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

</LinearLayout>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Follow Me"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_weight="0.09"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:textColor="#fefbf7"/>



<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Post Location on Facebook"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="0.09"
    android:background="#dfe3ee"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Message to Emergency Contact"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="#dfe3ee"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Without the error log is hard to determine if this is the only error in your code.

Comment: I have added my Logcat as an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your app from your mobile and remove from eclipse than try again...

Comment: you want me to remove that app from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the logcat output that you're using ActionBarActivity from the support library. In this case you have to use a theme that inherits from Theme.AppCompat as the logcat indicates. You cannot use the Holo themes.

Alternatively you could use Activity instead of ActionBarActivity, but you will be limited in the api versions you can support.